# DNN model gives different results at every run, is it the wrong architecture?

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, classification

I am not a deep learning expert and i was looking to a piece of code that exploits a 1D CNN to do a binary classification. The dataset is composed of different features extracted from an ECG recording(e.g. mean heart rate, max heart rate, max peaks distance, etc...) and a binary class(risk=1, no risk=0). I was wondering wether it makes sense to follow such approach because, in the literature, i have seen 1D CNNs applied to continuos signals, like the ECG recording itself and not a vector of features extracted from it.

I have this doubt because, while trying the piece of code reported below, **i obtained always very different results, in terms of classification,** at every run of the code; thus, exploring the possible causes of the problem, i questioned myself if the issue could lie on the structure of the model that is not correct for the dataset.

```
def network(X_train,y_train):

    K.clear_session() 
    im_shape=(X_train.shape[1],1)
    inputs_cnn=Input(shape=(im_shape), name='inputs_cnn')
    conv1_1=Convolution1D(64, (3), input_shape=im_shape, kernel_initializer='normal')(inputs_cnn)
    conv1_1=BatchNormalization()(conv1_1)
    pool1=MaxPool1D(pool_size=(3), strides=(1), padding="same")(conv1_1)
    flatten=Flatten()(pool1)
    dense_end1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(flatten)
    dense_end2 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(dense_end1)
    dense_end3 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(dense_end2)
    dense_end4 = Dense(32, activation='relu')(dense_end3)
    main_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(dense_end4)

    model = Model(inputs= inputs_cnn, outputs=main_output)
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(1e-6), loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics = ['accuracy'])

    callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=20)]

    history=model.fit(X_train, y_train,epochs=200, callbacks=callbacks, batch_size=8,validation_split=0.2, shuffle = False)
    return(model,history)

model,history=network(os_x_train,os_y_train) 
#model, history=network(ext_os_x_train,os_y_train) 
probas = model.predict(x_test)
preds = (probas > 0.5).astype(np.int) 
preds = preds.ravel()
```

One last clarification to frame the operations: os_x_train and os_y_train come from a part of the dataset that was oversampled. Obviously oversampling has not been applied to the x_test.

Comment: Have you ever heard of random weight initialization?

Comment: Yes, but it seems weird to me that random weight initialization disrupts the classification performance at each run of the code. I would imagine a slight change, but i am talking about big jumps in accuracy, sensitivity and specificity.

Comment: No, there are no guarantees at all here.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer, but i am still confused. How can i trust the results of a deep NN if running the same model from scratch does not converge to, more or less, the same result? i understand local minima problems, but still seems weird the absence of reproducibility of the experiments if the accuracy can vary so much. Sorry but, probably, i am missing something important